# Website sometimes gets jammed(timeout)

Tags: apache

I'm hosting my website [www.xgclan.com](http://www.xgclan.com) with the latest apache 2.4.1 and sometimes my server gets jammed, it doesn't seem to send any data but you don't get a timeout like when the Apache process isn't running.

A reboot of the process resolves this issue.
It seems to happen when you open the website in multiple browsers on the same system.

I've tested it on 2 different systems to make sure its not a bandwith or cpu problem.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this without the quotes "AcceptFilter http none" in the httpd.conf fixed the issue for me. 
I found the solution here: http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4543&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=20